# How to change the "Edit Page" frontend toolbar text in Wordpress? (Snippet)

Tags: php, wordpress, edit, toolbar, code-snippets

I am looking for a snippet function to replace the default "Edit Page" text that shows in the Wordpress toolbar.

I have disabled it on the backend altogether, because I am using a frontend builder for Editing pages and I want clients to understand which button does what. On the frontend I only have two options for an admin in the Toolbar > "Edit Page", "Edit Frontend". I want to change "Edit Page" to Edit Backend.

The "Edit Backend" text I think will suffice in the concept for where "Edit Page" would be "Edit Post", "Edit Product", etc. since the Frontend Builder handles all post types.

I would like a function snippet so I can leave the Wordpress core alone and updates are seamless.

I'm new here too, so thanks for listening and the help! 
You have already helped me learn a lot from other searches, but I now officially have an account.

UPDATE:

I wanted this snippet to just reflect when viewing the frontend of the site while logged in. The official code I've used to achieve this is below.

(I just wrapped Dylan's code in the is_admin)

The reason for this was frontend editors. I want it to be simple on the frontend saying "Edit Frontend" or "Edit Backend".

```
// Change The Edit Toolbar Text "Edit" to "Edit Backend"
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'change_admin_bar',999);

function change_admin_bar() {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('edit');

    $args = array(
        'id' => 'edit',
        'title' => 'Edit Backend',
       'href' => get_edit_post_link(),
    );

    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I misunderstood the question, but from what I gathered, you actually wanted to change the text of the WordPress admin bar so I've written up some code that can be placed in your functions.php file to do just that.

```
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'change_admin_bar',999);

function change_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('edit');

    $args = array(
        'id' => 'edit',
        'title' => 'Edit Backend',
       'href' => get_edit_post_link(),
    );

    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
```

Here are some sources for further research:
http://sumtips.com/2011/03/customize-wordpress-admin-bar.html
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar/add_node

Comment: Hey Dylan! Thanks! This is more of what I was looking for, though I can definitely keep the post type snippet for the future as I'm sure I will need it. 

Question... This ended up pushing my other text "Edit Frontend" all the way to left, which was good because it led me to apply some css to get the 2 toolbar options where I want then, centered on the frontend as fullwidth buttons. 

Though I can't find a lower element for the "Edit Backend" text to get it centered (ie float:right). 

Can I screenshot and ask you for idea/help here or would that be another question I should submit?

Comment: Glad I could help. And that sounds like you would probably get a better response by screenshotting it, and posting it here as a another question tagged as CSS.

Comment: For future reference, there is an entire community over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. If your question is specific to WordPress (NOT a plugin, or CSS), then you can usually get a good response over there.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to add that this created an Empty Item in the backend Wordpress toolbar. For anyone needing the same I added custom css  
".ab-empty-item {
  display: none !important;
}"

to make it disappear.

Comment: Just updating that I added an is_admin condition for this and posted the code above and why. - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This text is stored in post type labels. [reference to available labels](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).
If you want to change labels of default post types you'll need to redeclare this post type with smth like this (example for changing posts label to "News"):

```
function yourprefix_change_post_label() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add Article';
    $submenu['edit.php'][16][0] = 'Articles Tags';
    echo '';
}
function yourprefix_change_post_object() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Articles';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Article';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Article';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Article';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Article';
    $labels->new_item = 'New Article';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Article';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Articles';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Articles found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Articles found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All Articles';
    $labels->menu_name = 'Articles';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Articles';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'yourprefix_change_post_label' );
add_action( 'init', 'yourprefix_change_post_object' );
```

you can refer to [this article](http://revelationconcept.com/wordpress-rename-default-posts-news-something-else/) for more details.

Comment: Great this worked. I wanted to give my code back and ask a question. 

Well, I guess I can't give my code back as it too long to post in a comment. 

(Jeez... I submitted my comment twice early. They really should say that Shift + Enter adds a backspace and Enter alone submits a comment.)

Is this the only way or is there a simpler way to just change the text that appears in the toolbar? That is all I want and just want to make sure I'm not adding extra code not needed. But this does work and easy. I did it for posts and pages.

Comment: Just too add, it would benefit another if you can edit the example to say something like "Article" instead. The reason is because the initially learning curve I had to apply because whether singular or plural "News" is the same. Using something like "Article" would instantly let me know where to use the singular and plural form .. "Article" vs. "Articles".

Comment: @NoahjChampion I've updated the answer and now it creates a plural and singular labels. Hope this will help.  
as for your previous comment, I don't know any easier or less code way to achieve what you want on default post types.

Comment: Great, looks good. Question... can I seriously not vote you up until I gain 15 points from answering questions? Sorry about that, but I can't vote you up. 

Hey sorry about that. I see the difference now. I can check off that this answer was correct and worked. Thanks again! Have a good week.

Comment: I am glad this worked for you. Have a nice week also :)